# How to make custom title bar in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I really don't understand how to create this custom title bar.
I have tried about 5 different options and none of them worked. Can you please advise me on how to move the pyqt5 window by dragging the blue bar that I created (self.frame_WINDOW_HINT in the code)?

**Here is the code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from sys import exit, argv

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(420, 221)
        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(11, 19, 43);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 158, 401, 51))
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN.setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit {\n"
                                              "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    \n"
                                              "    font: 10pt \"Yu Gothic UI Semilight\";\n"
                                              "}")
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_MAIN")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 251, 51))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                                      "    background-color: rgb(28, 37, 65);\n"
                                                      "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                                      "    font: 75 17pt \"Verdana\";\n"
                                                      "    padding-bottom: 3px;\n"
                                                      "    border-radius: 13%\n"
                                                      "}\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "QPushButton::hover {\n"
                                                      "    \n"
                                                      "    background-color: rgb(233,37,57);\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "}\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "QPushButton::pressed {\n"
                                                      "    \n"
                                                      "    background-color: rgb(97, 14, 15);\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "}")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setObjectName("pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 421, 21))
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
                                 "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                 "    padding-left: 5px;\n"
                                 "    font: 75 9pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
                                 "}")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 421, 21))
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
                                             "    \n"
                                             "    \n"
                                             "    background-color: rgb(23, 39, 90);\n"
                                             "}")
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setObjectName("frame_WINDOW_HINT")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_WINDOW_HINT)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                                           "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                                                           "    image: url(:/icons/minimize_light_blue.png);\n"
                                                           "    border-radius: 100%;\n"
                                                           "}\n"
                                                           "\n"
                                                           "QPushButton::hover {\n"
                                                           "    image: url(:/icons/minimize_white.png);\n"
                                                           "    \n"
                                                           "    background-color: rgb(20, 35, 81);\n"
                                                           "}\n"
                                                           "\n"
                                                           "QPushButton::pressed {\n"
                                                           "    \n"
                                                           "    background-color: rgb(16, 29, 66);\n"
                                                           "}")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("minimize_light_blue.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setObjectName("pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_WINDOW_HINT)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                                        "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                                                        "    image: url(:/icons/close_light_blue.png);\n"
                                                        "    border-radius: 100%;\n"
                                                        "}\n"
                                                        "\n"
                                                        "QPushButton::hover {\n"
                                                        "    image: url(:/icons/close_white.png);\n"
                                                        "    background-color: rgb(233,37,57);\n"
                                                        "}\n"
                                                        "\n"
                                                        "QPushButton::pressed {\n"
                                                        "    \n"
                                                        "    background-color: rgb(149, 23, 38);\n"
                                                        "}")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setText("")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setObjectName("pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "------------------------------------"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried this, before class Ui_MainWindow, but the window would only move within its own window, while the main window remained in place.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from sys import argv, exit

class CustomTitleBar(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.parent().dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.parent().frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.parent().move(event.globalPos() - self.parent().dragPosition)
            event.accept()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(420, 221)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {\n"
                                 "    background-color: rgb(11, 19, 43);\n"
                                 "}")
        MainWindow.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame_MAIN = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_MAIN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 421, 221))
        self.frame_MAIN.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
                                      "    background-color: rgb(11, 19, 43);\n"
                                      "}")
        self.frame_MAIN.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_MAIN.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_MAIN.setObjectName("frame_MAIN")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_MAIN)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 251, 51))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                                      "    background-color: rgb(28, 37, 65);\n"
                                                      "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                                      "    font: 75 17pt \"Verdana\";\n"
                                                      "    padding-bottom: 3px;\n"
                                                      "    border-radius: 13%\n"
                                                      "}\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "QPushButton::hover {\n"
                                                      "    \n"
                                                      "    background-color: rgb(233,37,57);\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "}\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "QPushButton::pressed {\n"
                                                      "    \n"
                                                      "    background-color: rgb(97, 14, 15);\n"
                                                      "\n"
                                                      "}")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setObjectName("pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP")
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.frame_MAIN)
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 158, 401, 51))
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN.setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit {\n"
                                              "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    \n"
                                              "    font: 10pt \"Yu Gothic UI Semilight\";\n"
                                              "}")
        self.plainTextEdit_MAIN.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_MAIN")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 421, 21))
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
                                 "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                 "    padding-left: 5px;\n"
                                 "    font: 75 9pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
                                 "}")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT = CustomTitleBar(self.frame_MAIN)
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 421, 21))
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
                                             "    \n"
                                             "    \n"
                                             "    background-color: rgb(23, 39, 90);\n"
                                             "}")
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_WINDOW_HINT.setObjectName("frame_WINDOW_HINT")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_WINDOW_HINT)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                                           "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                                                           "    image: url(:/icons/minimize_light_blue.png);\n"
                                                           "    border-radius: 100%;\n"
                                                           "}\n"
                                                           "\n"
                                                           "QPushButton::hover {\n"
                                                           "    image: url(:/icons/minimize_white.png);\n"
                                                           "    \n"
                                                           "    background-color: rgb(20, 35, 81);\n"
                                                           "}\n"
                                                           "\n"
                                                           "QPushButton::pressed {\n"
                                                           "    \n"
                                                           "    background-color: rgb(16, 29, 66);\n"
                                                           "}")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("minimize_light_blue.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW.setObjectName("pushButton_MAIN_MINIMIZE_WINDOW")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_WINDOW_HINT)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                                        "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                                                        "    image: url(:/icons/close_light_blue.png);\n"
                                                        "    border-radius: 100%;\n"
                                                        "}\n"
                                                        "\n"
                                                        "QPushButton::hover {\n"
                                                        "    image: url(:/icons/close_white.png);\n"
                                                        "    background-color: rgb(233,37,57);\n"
                                                        "}\n"
                                                        "\n"
                                                        "QPushButton::pressed {\n"
                                                        "    \n"
                                                        "    background-color: rgb(149, 23, 38);\n"
                                                        "}")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setText("")
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW.setObjectName("pushButton_MAIN_CLOSE_WINDOW")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_MAIN_START_STOP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "------------------------------------"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: First of all, that is not a "navbar", but a title bar. Then, in the codes you're providing there is nothing that shows us how you're trying to use the UI and the custom frame, so please provide a valid [mre] of your attempts.

Comment: @musicamante Yeah, thank you for the correction. I meant titlebar. I have provided the full code with buggy attempt.

Comment: The `self.parent()` target is wrong. You created `CustomTitleBar` using `self.frame_MAIN`, and that becomes the parent of the title bar, but you want to move *the window*, so you should use `self.window()` instead. Note that you should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (even in [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)). Also, from your code it's not clear if you're properly using promoted widgets or you're editing the output of the pyuic file. In the first case, that is ok, in the second, it's **not**, as editing such files is considered bad practice.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, I changed self.parent() to self.window(), and now everything works as it should.